# My VBA code is so slow, any way could speed up the loading?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code, which I want to lock the cell if range column AT is Accepted/rejected/not processed, but it takes me 30 sec when I click on any cell on this sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX")
 
    Set rng = ws.Range("AT2:AT2000")
 
    For Each cell In rng
        ActiveSheet.Protect "123"
        If CStr(cell.Value) = "Accepted" Or CStr(cell.Value) = "Rejected" Or CStr(cell.Value) = "Not Processed" Then
        If Range("AM2:AS2000").Locked <> True Then Range("AM2:AS2000").Locked = True

        ElseIf IsError(cell.Value) Or IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123"
 
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = False
        rng.Locked = True
 
        End If
 
    Next cell
 
ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
ws.Protect Contents:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
 
    
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123"

End Sub
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out what your intentions are here! Why do you apply this arduous testing to the entire range "AT2:AT2000" when you already know which target cell has been changed in the spreadsheet? If the target cell isn't in that range you can return immediately unless there are side effects. Code indentation could do with some work too. Range("AM2:AS2000").Locked=TRUE can come out of the loop and there is no need to test before doing it either. Likewise don't call CStr each time (if you need to at all!) put the result of the reference into a variable and test that!

Comment: I was going to answer with a cleaned up version of your code but the more I look at it, the more I get confused as to what you're trying to achieve. Is the ActiveSheet the same as `ws`? If not, what is ws doing here anyway? Why protect a sheet, to unlock it after if you're only changing `.Locked` status? Wouldn't it be easier to just lock the cell's row of column AM instead of everything?

Comment: Inside the loop you read cell.Value 5 times: it's cleaner to read it *once* into a variable, then work with that variable.  Every read from the sheet costs you time.

Answer (score 1):

You do `ActiveSheet.Protect` and `ActiveSheet.Unprotect`, which are both very heavy operations, inside the loop. Pull them out and only do them once.

Comment: If i pull them out, i couldn't lock my cell in this way. May you share another way which can achieve similar result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no difference for locking, if the protect is inside or outside. Just keep the desired locking status in a variable and set it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("AT2:AT2000")
    if application.intersect(target, rng) is nothing then exit sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123"
    if (target.value = "Accepted" Or _
        Target.value = "Rejected" Or _
        Target.value = "Not Processed") then 
            range(cells(target.row, 39),cells(target.row,45)).locked=true
        else 
            target.entirerow.locked=false 
            
    End If
    activesheet.Protect "123"
End Sub
```